# Filtering values from a Python list based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Got a simple question about Python lists. I am trying to read a csv file that has some data as below:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
```

I am able to extract file value of the csv file based on index but not able to filter corresponding value. Given below is a sample view of the data in the csv file

```
name,parent,child
Apple,iPhone,iPhoneX
Samsung,Note,Note 5
```

Could anyone assist, how could I extract values such as iPhone and iPhoneX from the above. Thanks..

Comment: use line = strip(',') , then you can go line[1] for parent and line[2] for child

Comment: Also note: `f.read().splitlines()` is equivalent to `f.readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DictReader, as described in https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html, the values in the first row of the file will be used as the fieldnames (attributes) of each row

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['name'], row['parent'], row['child'])
```

Answer (score 4):

The file is a CSV file. Why not take a few steps back and treat it as such?

By using `csv.DictReader` the indexes are totaly encapsulated by the column names:

```
import csv 

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print(line['parent'], line['child'])
```

output

```
# iPhone iPhoneX
# Note Note 5
```

If for some reason you insist on dealing with indexes, you can do that as well:

```
import csv 

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skipping the header line
    for line in reader:
        print(line[1], line[2])
```

output

```
# iPhone iPhoneX
# Note Note 5
```

Comment: one another help, if I were to pass any of these values by index to a variable would var_name = line[1] work.

Comment: @darkhorse Why wouldn't it?